# User authentication in contentful CMS

Tags: android, authentication, content-management-system, contentful

As per my understanding, Contentful CMS supports Application level authentication via OAuth and Access tokens. I am looking for user level authentication support, where I have/grant limited number of users to access. I can add or delete user at times.

Is user level authentication supported in contentful?

Is there any 3rd party solution providing the interface for the same?

I couldn't see any user db/content model/type nor any API which I can use for user level authentication.

Please clarify If I am wrong.

Thanks for your time and help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contentful has OAuth and authentication for its APIs.

This means that you can granularily give users access to different parts of the API. You can also give access to the actual content via API access tokens.

However this does *not*  provide any authentication mechanism suitable for your application. You have to build that yourself or use something suitable for the tech stack you're using.